# lot and lof are having wrong pagenumber in toc

Tags: thesis

I am using isu thesis class with some modification.A wrong page number appears for lot and lof in the toc as wn below.All other page numbers are correct.Kindly help me

sho[image]

```
% Template file for a standard thesis
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,justified]{isuthesis}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cc]{titlepic}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% Standard, old-style thesis
\usepackage{isutraditional}   \chaptertitle
% Old-style, thesis numbering down to subsubsection
\alternate
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
% Bibliography without numbers or labels
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\includeonly{titletoc,chapter1}
%Optional Package to add PDF bookmarks and hypertext links


\usepackage[hypertexnames=true,linktocpage=false]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true,pdfview=FitB}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
%\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\addtocontents{toc}{{Contents}\hfill{Page No.}\par}
\addtocontents{lot}{{No.}\hfill{Title}~\hfill{Page No.}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{{No.}\hfill{Title}~\hfill{Page No.}\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{}} \cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
\pdfbookmark[1]{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{table}
\cleardoublepage \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{CHAPTER\ }}
%Optional Acknowledgements
\cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\chead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.pdf,.mps,.png,.eps,.tif}
\begin{document}


%\cfoot{\thepage}
%\chead{}
\include{Preface/titlepage}
% Optional thesis dedication
\include{Preface/dedication}
\include{Preface/certificate}
% Table of Contents, List of Tables and List of Figures

\tableofcontents


\listoftables

\listoffigures
% Comment out the next line if NOT using chaptertitle

\include{Preface/acknowl}
%Optional thesis abstract

\include{Preface/abstract}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{~~~#1}{\\ \MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}{\centering\large\bfseries}{\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}


\makeatother
\newpage
%\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{Body/chapter1}
\include{Body/chapter2}
\include{Body/chapter3}
\include{Body/chapter4}
\include{Body/chapter5}
\include{Appendix/appendix1}
\include{Appendix/appendix2}

%\include{Reference/bibtex}
\include{Reference/biblio}
\end{document}
```

[Please access the folder from this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1UK76PqW_WYNHNNSmc4SmlaZE0/view?usp=sharing)

I have used `\usepackage{tocbibind}`but now toc is showing like this, Acknowledgement should be start from page i and no need of the term " CONTENTS "in toc [image]

and references like

[image]

Comment: Did you compile a second time?

Comment: Yes. I have compiled second time

Comment: Well then, unless your LoF and LoT actually fits on one page *together* and is set that way, we would need more information to address your question.

Comment: Actually lot and lof are coming in vi and vii pages.

Comment: ...so everything works now?

Comment: No Sir. Actually lot and lof are coming on vi and vii pages.But it appears in toc as wrong like mentioned above.

Comment: We will need a minimal example of your document.

Comment: Yes I am edited my question and added the main code.

Comment: Are those isu class and packages publicly available? Also can you prepare a version we can compile. We of course does not have access to the files you include

Comment: Btw: if you have to use a specific setup for the thesis, are you then allowed to modify the layout?

Comment: @daleif : Actually, there is another thesis style by our university.So we need to change isu layout to our university's layout. ISU thesis and style is publicly available in internet.we have downloaded it and going to change for our university.

Comment: @daleif : how can I share the file to you for compiling

Comment: Update your question with the link

Comment: @daleif : I have updated my question with link to access the folder

Comment: @LaRiFaRi  : I have updated my question with link to access the folder

Comment: @Werner  : I have updated my question with link to access the folder

Comment: You probably have to drop `tocbibind` and resort to hackery instead. It does not seem to be compatible with the `\specialchapt` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too little space for this comment)

Looking closer the problem is these lines as the start (before `\begin{document}`

```
 \cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
\pdfbookmark[1]{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{table}
\cleardoublepage \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{CHAPTER\ }}
```

This means these entries will get the page number of the start of the document, thus the behaviour you see.

Those lines should of course accompany `\listoffigures` etc

But it cannot because of the `\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{CHAPTER\ }}` line which adds `Chapter into the Toc entries.

My recommendation: please have a look at the `tocbibind` package (for automatic inclusing of lot and lof into the toc) and the `tocloft` package for configuring the TOC (it has build in features to prefix chapter entries)

---

Edit: I can see the `\@chapapp` in the TOC entries comes from the class. That was not a nice away of doing that if a user wanted to add LOF and LOT into the TOC. You will need to move

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{CHAPTER\ }}
```

after `\listoffigures`

---

Edit 2: The class does not work well with `tocbibind` so we'll have to do things manually. This works for me

```
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
% Comment out the next line if NOT using chaptertitle

\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{CHAPTER\ }}
```

Note the placement of the last line, it has to moved here from the preamble.

Comment: I have edited the code and now showing some errors.Further I edited the question and mentioned the errors.

Comment: As I mentioned in my edit to the answer, you need to move the `\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{CHAPTER\ }}` else where.